# LinkedList : Collections.max() throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, collections, nosuchelementexception

I am not iterating the `LinkedList` by any means like scanner or other methods, I am using `Collections.max()` to get maximum number from the `LinkedList`.

I have read on Stack Overflow that this exception is thrown due to iterator or scanner or tokenizer, but I am using none of them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TLG {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        LinkedList<Integer> first = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> second = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        int cases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for(int i=1;i<=cases;i++) {
            String score = br.readLine();
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt(score.split(" ")[0]); 
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(score.split(" ")[1]); 
            int diff = number1 - number2;

            if(diff > 0){
                first.add(diff);    
            }
            else {
                second.add(java.lang.Math.abs(diff));    
            }
        }

        Integer max1 = Collections.max(first);  // Getting Exception here
        Integer max2 = Collections.max(second); // Getting Exception here

        if(max1 > max2) {
            System.out.println(1+" "+max1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(2+" "+max2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do `first` and `second` have any elements in them?

Comment: What is the value of `cases`?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input data that result in this Exception, which you believe should not?

Comment: Also you can't have the exception on both lines, either you get it on the first or the second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must be calling `Collections.max()` on an empty `List`.

As the Javadoc states, this results in `NoSuchElementException`:

> **<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T java.util.Collections.max(Collection<? extends T> coll)**
>
> ...
>
> **Throws:**
>
> ClassCastException - if the collection contains
> elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers).
>
> **NoSuchElementException - if the collection is empty.**

Comment: But My LInklists are not empty, I removed the Collections.max() line and printed the linked list found:
5
5 6 : None of them are empty..
10 20
20 10
6 5
22 65
First Linkedlist element: [10, 1]
Second Linkedlist element: [1, 10, 43]

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc he's making a point at the cost of the quality of his answer.

Comment: MyLinkedLists are not empty I printed them and there are values in them.

Comment: @PankajKushwaha Then this exception cannot happen. Please try to debug your program to see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

you are calling  Collections.max() with empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking against Empty case: So `Collections.max()` will throw `NoSuchElementException`

First check if any of the Lists is Empty (then you know the max and which list is providing it)

```
    Integer max;
    int list;
    if (first.isEmpty()) {
        max = Collections.max(second);
        list = 2;
    } else if (second.isEmpty()) {
        max = Collections.max(first);
        list = 1;
    } else {
        Integer max1 = Collections.max(first);
        Integer max2 = Collections.max(second);
        if (max1 > max2) {
            max = max1;
            list = 1;
        } else {
            max = max2;
            list = 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list + " " + max);
```

Comment: You are only hiding the problem there.. The real question is why these lists are empty?

Comment: @user2336315 Not really, what if `int diff = number1 - number2;` is always positive? Then `diff` will always be on the first list